# Pandas .to_csv(fileName, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE ERRORTypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quoting'

Tags: python, pandas, quoting

Attempting to write a data frame to csv using pandas and remove quotes produced by a concatenated value. The interpreter is not accepting the argument quoting.

ERROR

> TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quoting'

CODE

concatenation producing double quote in value:

```
df['NAME'] = df[['Last', 'First']].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x), axis =1)

df2 = df[['NAME']].copy()

df2.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_csv(_testFileout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

OUTPUT(Without quoting argument):

```
2,"LAST, FIRST"
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
2,LAST, FIRST
```

Written to file

Versions:

PYTHON 3.6.4

PANDAS 0.22.0

COMPLETED CODE

import pandas as pd

_testFile = 'G:\SOMEFILEPATH.csv'

_testFileout = 'G:\ANOTHERPATH.txt'

df = pd.read_csv(_testFile, encoding='utf-8')

df['1'] = '*'

df['2'] = df[['Last', 'First']].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x), axis =1)

df['45'] = df['userid']

df['50'] = '2'

df['75'] = '1'

df['150'] = df['First']+'.'+df['Last']+'@xxxx.com'

df['2401'] = 'Document Imaging'

df['2402'] = df['userid']

df['2403'] = 'imagelater'

df['2405'] = 'Yes'

df['20700'] = '201'

df['20701'] = '000' + df['employeeID'].astype(str)

df2 = df[['1', '2', '45', '50', '75', '150', '2401', '2402', '2403', '2405', '20700','20701']].copy()

df2.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_csv(_testFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

**NEW CODE**

**df2.stack().reset_index(level=0,drop=True).to_frame().to_csv(_testFileout, quoting=3, escapechar="\r")**

Comment: Why not just do `df2 = df[['Last', 'First']].copy()` and then `df2.to_csv(...)`?

Comment: I've shortened the code there are several columns being copied to the new df.

Comment: Then `columns = ['columns', 'to', 'copy']` and `df2 = df[columns].copy()`. Or just drop the columns you don't need: `df2 = df.drop(columns=columns_to_drop).copy()`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow/help/mcve) so we can help.

Comment: Uploading Completed Example

Comment: Engineero- About the same amount of columns to drop as to copy in my input file. So i picked copy.

Answer (score 2):

`stack` on a simple index (i.e. not a MultiIndex) produces a Series, not a DataFrame. If that's the case here, as it appears to be, what you're calling is the Series `to_csv` not the DataFrame one, which does not have the `quoting` parameter.

If you need to have a DataFrame (in case you do need to use `quoting`, just call `to_frame` and use an `escapechar`:

```
df2.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_frame().to_csv(filename, escapechar='\\', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: This is correct this is a single tiered Index so I cannot remove the quotes. What im producing is a flat file which needs to be in the format produced by the stack. Column,value seperated by a comma stacked on top of each other. This file will be uploaded to a database.

Comment: In that case, just call to_frame prior to to_csv. Make sure to set an escape character; you can't use to_csv with embedded commas in the field without either quoting or an escape character set.  I'll edit my answer if this works for you.

Comment: Can you post your new code and output?  When I add .to_frame() between .stack and .to_csv it gives what you describe, with each row having one label and its associated value.

Comment: I got it to work, the problem was that i needed to use an escape char that wouldn't show up in the output so I used "\r" carriage return. Posting updated code.